# Recursion - what's the difference with this BST?

Tags: c++

So I sometimes hiccup a bit on recursion. What ultimately is the difference logically between this:

```
Node *lca(Node *root, int v1,int v2) {
    // Write your code here.
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    // If both v1 and v2 are less than node->data, lies on the left
    if (v1 < root->data && v2 < root->data)
    {
        return lca(root->left, v1, v2);
    }
    
    if (v1 > root->data && v2 > root->data)
    {
        // if v1 and v2 are greater than node->data, then it lies on
        // the right of the binary search tree
        return lca(root->right, v1, v2);
    }
    
    // Otherwise, we have one on the left and one on the right,
    // so let's return root as that will be our lowest common ancestor
    return root;
}
```

and this:

```
Node *lca(Node *root, int v1,int v2) {
    // Write your code here.
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    // If both v1 and v2 are less than node->data, lies on the left
    if (v1 < root->data && v2 < root->data)
    {
        lca(root->left, v1, v2);
    }
    
    if (v1 > root->data && v2 > root->data)
    {
        // if v1 and v2 are greater than node->data, then it lies on
        // the right of the binary search tree
        lca(root->right, v1, v2);
    }
    
    // Otherwise, we have one on the left and one on the right,
    // so let's return root as that will be our lowest common ancestor
    return root;
}
```

I try to sometimes go through it in my head but I then get stuck in a recursive loop myself! Why is the latter not correct?

Comment: The second fragment calls `lca` recursively, but doesn't actually use its return value in any way. It always returns `root` - the rest of the code is pointless. In other words, it's equivalent to `Node *lca(Node *root, int v1,int v2) { return root; }` The rest is busywork with no effect whatsoever.

Comment: A second logic difference: the first fragment has 4 returns,  which means that only one return will be called *the code exits in that return).  In particular, is not possible for BOTH the middle 2 recursive calls to occur.   The second fragment has only two returns.  This means that it is possible for BOTH the middle 2 recursive calls to occur.  We know nothing about the kinds of data in v1 and v2 relative to the contents in the tree, so we find no logic to prevent BOTH recursions to be called (in the one invocation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one does NOT return what it found. it returns only NULL or root.

Let's try to check with following example:

```
   3  <-- root
 /   \
1     5
 \   /
  2 4
```

If you call `lca(root, 1, 2)`, the first one returns *pointer for a instance of Node*.

Then you can use it as:

```
Node *found = lca(root, 1, 2);
int answer = found->data;  // whatever you want
```

BUT the second one can not be this.

Details on code: https://ideone.com/oZdW6k

If you doesn't like use a return, it can be fixed as like:

```cpp
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// The third one (no return, but fixed)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void lca(Node *src, Node *dst, int v1, int v2) {
    if (src == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    if (v1 < src->data && v2 < src->data) {
        lca(src->left, dst, v1, v2);
        *dst = *src->left;
        return;
    }
    
    if (v1 > src->data && v2 > src->data) {
        lca(src->right, dst, v1, v2);
        *dst = *src->right;
        return;
    }

    *dst = *src;
}

int main(){
    // root = ..... (initialize whatever)
    Node result;
    lca(root, &result, 1, 2);
    printf("%d\n", result.data);
    return 0;
}
```

You could check this at: https://ideone.com/bLvAnw

and, one more thing I could say.

It is same with following if conditions:

```cpp
    if (v1 < src->data && v2 < src->data) {
        // left...
    } else if (v1 > src->data && v2 > src->data) {
        // right...
    } else {
        // current node
    }
```